# How to create a event in android calendar for custom account?

Tags: android, synchronization, android-calendar

I want to add my own server calendar events to android. I already done contact synchronization from my custom account.

But I cannot find code for **create a event in calendar for my custom account.**

any source code or links welcome.

Answer (score 0):

you have to create the event and add it to the calendar with the

```
 ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
 values.put(some parameter..., value);

 contentResolver.insert(CalendarContract.events, values );
```

The key of the thing is that you have to bind your event to the calendar by the ID of the calendar.  So one of the parameter should be look like this in values.put()

```
 values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, calID);
```

Tutorial on this site [Add event to calendar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#add-event)